# How to display the node id as a field (with label)

Tags: 7, entities

This question is really simple, i need to use the node id as an identifier and so i need to display it whenever a certain content type is shown. What's the best way to do this? 
i need to display the node with label and so on, i just don't want to make a custom field for something that's already a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) hook and copy the nid into a field like structure.

something like (*untested*)

```
function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->nid_field['und']['value'] = $node->nid;
  }
}
```

Comment: and then do what with it? This answer is pretty vague.

Comment: this was more like i thought because i wanted the nid to act like a field with a label and so on.

Comment: Added some sample code.

Comment: It makes little sense to use the _load hook to add something that is already there. Load is for adding *new* data (or changing existing data).

Answer (score 4):

Create a template for the content type and use `<?php print $node->nid; ?>`

Make a copy of node.tpl.php from modules/system and paste in your theme directory.  Copy the code from inside node.tpl.php and create a new file called "node--YOURTYPE.tpl.php" (replace YOURTYPE with the name of the content type).

Inside that file you can place `<?php print $node->nid; ?>` wherever you want the nid to be seen.  You can add a label, wrap it in HTML to style it, whatever you like. Save the file and clear the cache to see the changes.  Take a look at a node of that content type and you will see the node's nid.

Comment: @Nicola if you want a label, simply add it into the template with HTML...

Answer (score 2):

1. download display suite module.
2. add a custom code field
3. select token and the code is  [node:nid]